# What is the difference of these two java data structure?

Tags: java, arrays, class

The first version is:

```
int[] a = new int[1000];
int[] b = new int[1000];
```

The second version is:

```
class Helper{
    int a;
    int b;
}
Helper[] c = new Helper[1000];
```

My intuition tells me that the second one is better, but I could persuade myself in reason.... 
Can anyone compare the time complexity and space complexity of these two structure for me. For example, are these two version cost the same space? Or the second one cost less?
Thank you!

Comment: Quick answer: google "parallel arrays vs structures". That'll give you a number of takes on it.

Comment: Without more context, we can't say for sure if the second is better. It depends on how related they are conceptually.

Comment: Try sorting helpers by their `aa` property with both options.

Comment: The in-memory structure is different! There is an advanced performance aspect independent of program design questions already mentioned by others here.  [Read this document (PDF) "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory"](http://futuretech.blinkenlights.nl/misc/cpumemory.pdf). Basically, depending on your computations(!) you might end up with bad data access patterns - but that could be the case with either of your two structures, because it depends on what exactly you do, what data the CPU needs at each step. As I said, this is an advanced topic! Ignore if you are learning to program.

Answer (score 4):

The real question you should be asking is what is the relation between `aa[i]` and `bb[i]`. If `aa[i]` and `bb[i]` are properties of the same object (that has a more meaningful description than "Helper"), you should definitely put them in some class instead of using multiple primitive arrays. After all, Java is an object oriented language.

You shouldn't care about performance differences. Those will be insignificant. The important thing is that you code makes sense to whoever reads it.

Comment: Also, a `List` should be preferred over an array. `Arrays.asList` makes that transformation easy.

Comment: @4castle That depends on the use-case. If the OP needs a fixed sized container whose size is known in advance, an array is more efficient than a List.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` just returns a wrapper `List` implementation that stores a reference to the same array. It's still fixed size also.

Comment: @4castle True, but it still adds some overhead (creating an additional object, even though it's just a wrapper).

Comment: I've never been in a situation where the tiny overhead of using a `List` created any observable problems. There are more important ways to optimize.

Comment: @4castle Well, there's still the question of why wrap an array with a List instance if you don't need to? If you feel using the List interface makes your code clearer, than that's a good reason to use it. The main down-side I can see with using `Arrays.asList` is that it returns a `List`, which gives no indication that it has a fixed size (until you try to add or remove an element and get an exception).

Answer (score 1):

While Eran is right, I'll add a few more points.

Sure, chances are you're very likely not going to bother about the performance - the difference is very insignificant for a general purpose application. **Readability is what matters**.

Still, in terms of **technical details**:

Space complexity is the same (it's always as many elements you have), but the absolute value in bytes is different.

Array of pairs will cost you more - each Java object has an overhead of several bytes. In case of two arrays, it's only a few bytes overhead per each array.

Also, in case of two arrays, the values of each array will reside next to each other in memory - reading all values of one of those array will be more effective in terms of CPU cache and memory layout. In case of array of objects, you now have an array of links to those objects and need first read the address of the object, before you can access the actual value of the field.

These are just general points so you can get a feeling of what's going on. In practice it all depends on how you want to work with those structures.